# TypeORM - How to defined the database name for a entity

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm using two Postgres databases `db1` and `db2`.
And each database X number of tables.
With `nestjs` and `typeorm` how can define the name of the database who belongs to a specific entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeORM's configuration has an `entities` array, that defines if an entity belongs to a database connection or not. That's what you should be using. Otherwise, your entity should just be a class decorated accordingly. [Connection Options Documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/connection-options/common-connection-options)